# Construct a morphism from a nonsigular projective curve onto $\mathbb{P}^1$ from a rational function, and its quasi-finiteness (I)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

I'm currently doing exercise I.6.4 in Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry. I've tried to prove this and get a so-called "proof" which full of gaps and uncertainty.

The exercise goes like this:

> Let $Y$ be a nonsingular projective curve. Show that:
> (1) every nonconstant rational function $f$ defined on $Y$ defines a surjective morphism $\phi: Y \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$,
> (2) and that for every $P \in \mathbb{P}^1$, $\phi^{-1}(P)$ is a finite set of points.

**"Proof" of (1)**: I get the inspiration from Question: [Rational function and morphisms of quasiprojective varieties](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1145136/rational-function-and-morphisms-of-quasiprojective-varieties)

By saying $f$ is a rational function on $Y$, we are actually given a regular function on an open set $U \subset Y$. WLOG, we may assume that $U$ here has already be maximal. What we need to do is actually define the desired morphsim on $Y-U$. To do that, consider any (fixed) point $P \in Y-U$ and the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{Y,P}$ with the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_P$. Note that $Y$ is a nonsingular projective curve, $\mathcal{O}_{Y,P}$ is a DVR, and hence $\mathfrak{m}_P$ is principal. Let $\mathfrak{m}_P = (u)$.

Since $P \in Y-U$, $f$ is not contained in that local ring. Yet since $f$ is a rational function, $f \in \mathrm{Frac}(\mathcal{O}_{Y,P})=K(Y)$. Hence we can write $f$ as $f=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$, where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathcal{O}_{Y,P}$ and $\beta \not\in (\mathcal{O}_{Y,P})^\times$. By definition, $\beta \in \mathfrak{m}_P$. Hence, there exists $\beta_1 \in \mathcal{O}_{Y,P}$, such that $\beta = \beta_1 u$.

Now if $\beta_1 \not\in \mathfrak{m}_P$, then $\frac{\alpha}{\beta_1}$ is regular amd nonzero at $P$ and $f$ can be expressed as $f=(\alpha / \beta_1) u^{-1}$. Else if $\beta_1 \in \mathfrak{m}_P$, we can carry on the process above and find $\beta_2 \in \mathcal{O}_{Y,P}$ such that $f=(\alpha / \beta_2) u^{-2}$. Such process will end in finitely many steps, for if not, we would obtain a chain $\beta_j \vert \beta_{j-1}$, which contradicts to the fact that $\mathcal{O}_{Y,P}$ is a UFD (since it is a DVR).

To sum up, we can express $f$ as $f= \rho u^{-\nu}$ for some $\rho$ a regular and nonzero at $p$ map, and $\nu$ a positive integer.

Now, we define $\phi(P)$ as
$$
\phi(P) = [0:1] = [u^{\nu}(P) : \rho(P)],
$$
when $P \in Y-U$. For $P \in Y$, we can define
$$
\phi(P) = [1:f(P)].
$$
This is consistent with the definition for $P \in Y-P$, if we now regard $f=u^{0} f$ by taking $\nu = 0$ in above settings.

Now, here come my **Question 1**: **Why $\phi$ is a morphism?**

If we have proved that $\phi$ is a morphism, then since $\phi$ is a morphism from a PROJECTIVE curve $Y$, the image is closed in $\mathbb{P}^1$. Since $f$ is nonconstant and $Y$ is irreducible, the image of $\phi$ must be all of $\mathbb{P}^1$. Hence $\phi$ is a surjection.

Here comes my **Question 2**: The "proof" above seems to be a complete one. Yet it is too complicated! **Is there a better way to understand the proof?** I've read some post on MSE about this question, and someone mentioned that we can use the Proposition I.6.8 in Hartshorne "directly" to get the desired result. But I do not know how to apply this theorem here. **Could someone provide more details on this?**

P.S.The Proposition I.6.8 in Hartshorne is:

> Let $X$ be an abstract nonsigular curve, let $P$ \in $X$ and $Y$ be a projective variety. Let $\phi: X-P \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism. Then there exists a unique morphism $\bar{\phi}: X \rightarrow Y$ extending $\phi$.

I still have questions on (b), yet since this question has already been quite lengthy, I will open up another post on those.

I'm so sorry to post such a lengthy post. and thank you all for answering and commenting on this post in advance!! :)

Comment: By using induction in Proposition I.6.8., you can replace $P$ with any finite subset. But recall that the topology on a curve is exactly the cofinite topology – so this means that you can extend morphisms from open subsets of smooth curves to the curves themselves.

Comment: Aha, haven't come up with such an "easy" argument. Thank you! :)

Comment: And may be useful for later viewers, here is a post on the zariski topology on a curve: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360157/zariski-topology-irreducible-affine-curve-is-same-as-the-cofinite-topology .

Answer (score 1):

**Exercise:** "Let $Y$ be a nonsingular projective curve. Show that: (1) every nonconstant rational function $f$ defined on $Y$ defines a surjective morphism $ϕ:Y→P^1$, (2) and that for every $P∈P^1$, $ϕ^{−1}(P)$ is a finite set of points."

**Answer:** Let $C$ be an irreducible smooth projective curve over an algebraically closed field $k$ and let $K:=K(C)$ be the function field of $C$ with $x\in K$ a "non-constant" rational function. Let $P(t)\in k[t]$ and assume $P(x)=0$. Since $k$ is algebraically closed this implies $x\in k$ a contradiction, hence $x$ is "transcendental over $k$", meaning the subring $k[x] \subseteq K$ generated by $k$ and $x$ is isomorphic to a polynomial ring. You get an embedding $k \subseteq k(x) \subseteq K$ where $x$ behaves like an independent variable over $k$. This gives (by the proof of HH.I.6.12) a surjective morphism

$$\phi: C \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1_k.$$

Since $C$ is projective and irreducible, the image is closed and irreducible and hence $Im(\phi)=\mathbb{P}^1_k$. The inverse image $\phi^{-1}(x)$ of a closed point $x\in \mathbb{P}^1_k$ is a strict closed subvariety of $C$ (since $\phi$ is non-constant) and since $C$ is irreducible it follows $\phi^{-1}(x)$ must be a finite set of points.

**Note:** Since $k$ is algebraically closed it follows any polynomial $P(t) \in k[t]$ factors as

$$P(t)=(t-a_1)\cdots (t-a_n)$$

with $a_i \in k$. Hence if $P(x)=0$ it follows $x=a_i\in k$ for some $i$ - a contradiction since $x$ is assumed to be "non-constant".

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice exercise, and it should be discusses clearly in my opinion. Since you gave a reference to an exercise in Hartshorne's book, I will use the definitions and results in this book.

First of all, we have the following easy fact ( it basically follows from the first section):
If $X$ is a curve, then $C\subset X$ is closed if and only if either $C=X$ or $C$ is finite.

Let $\langle U,f \rangle$  be a rational function in $K(Y)$. Then $f: U\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1$ is a nonconstant morphism by definition, so $f(U)$ is not a point. Observe that $f(U)$ is dense in $\mathbb{A}^1$. Indeed, if it was not dense, then it should be the set of points. But, since $f$ is regular, it is continuous by Lemma I.3.1. Thus $f(U)$ should be irreducible, so $f(U)$ would be only one point, which is a contradiction. Hence we have a dominant morphism  $f: U\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1.$

Let $U_1$ be the open set defined by the equation $x_1\neq 0$ as in page 10. Then we have an isomorphism $\varphi_1: U_1\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1$ by Proposition I.3.3. Note that $U_1$ is a (quasi)-projective variety. Then the map $\varphi':=\varphi_1^{-1}f:U\rightarrow U_1$ is a dominant morphism of varieties. (Here, $U_1\subset \mathbb{P}^1$) Since $U$ is nonempty, open, $Y-U$ is finite. Thus, by Proposition I.6.8 and induction, $\varphi'$ uniquely extends to a morphism $\varphi: Y\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$. Strictly speaking, to use Proposition I.6.8, we also need to say that $Y$ is an abstract nonsingular curve, which follows from Proposition I.6.7.

I will not discuss the second part since hm2020's answer has already discussed it in detail.

In your first question, you are saying why is $\varphi$ a morphism? Are you asking whether it is a morphism or not? Even though the idea seems true for me, I am not sure it is really a morphism. So you should either show that it is a morphism (by using the definition) or use some results. I wrote the idea seems true because you are sending point at infinity to the finite points in $Y-U$. It may work.